# What does "Fortune fame mirror vain" mean in Metallica's The Memory Remains?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, metallica

I was wondering what does chrous of The Memory Remains mean?
"Fortune Fame, Mirror Vain, Gone Insane, But The Memory Remains"
I asked this because it doesn't mean what it looks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sachi speculates](https://sachi13.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/83/):

> The first two lines probably go together in a sentence as “Fortune,
>   fame mirror vain” and can translate to “both fortune and fame mirror
>   what is vain.” So this basically says that **fame and fortune reflect
>   false pride, or baseless pride. That one who has those things and
>   waves them around do so to express how proud they are, but to no avail**
>   (another definition of the word “vain”). And then it goes to the next
>   line, **“gone insane”, to express how one goes insane from their false
>   pride of fame and fortune, or simply grows too attached to the fame
>   and can’t stand to lose it**. However, they can’t get over this anxiety
>   of losing fame because “[…] the memory remains”.

BTW the correct lyrics are (note the comma in the first line):

> Fortune, fame
>
> Mirror vain
>
> Gone Insane
>
> But the memory remains

As shown in this lyric booklet that accompanies a Japanese release:

[image]

Comment: I have always thought vain was incorrect.

Comment: I'd have to agree whit BCdotWEB it makes more sense, plus when they sing the song they don't sound like their taking a pause between fortune and fame. Other wise it just wouldn't flow well.

Answer (score 0):

The song is all about faded Hollywood stars who have passed their "best before" date. The most credible explanation that I could find is one by someone called FilmScorpio [here](https://songmeanings.com/songs/view/36974/?&specific_com=73014889472#comments). According to that source, then almost every single line from the lyrics including the mirror/vain part refers to something in the 1950s movie *Sunset Boulevard*. I guess one has to see that movie to tell for sure.

Also they hand-picked [Marianne Faithfull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marianne_Faithfull) for the choiring and some part of the lyrics - with her personal story would be a similar one of someone going from celebrity to tragedy.

The line ""Say yes, at least say hello" read by Marianne at the end is according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Memory_Remains) a reference to another movie *The Misfits*, "the last complete movie in which Marilyn Monroe starred".